# How to avoid Space sensitivity of MySQL data

Tags: mysql, sql, whitespace

I have a record like "John Carter" with the space between two names. Now I want to search the word with the help of WHERE condition like (WHERE NAME="JohnCarter") without space, but due to the space sensitivity query returns me false, so is there any solution to avoid this space sensitivity.

| Id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John Carter |
| 2 | Rosy Foster |

$name='JohnCarter';
$result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `profile` WHERE name='$name'");
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
echo 'true';}else{echo 'false'}

Comment: Uh, why do you need to search without a space? `where replace(name, ' ', '') = 'JohnCarter'` should work, but of course won't help with the typo in the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be the ideal situation to use a soundex function. MySQL has such a function builtin:

```
mysql> select soundex('John Carter'), soundex('JhonCarter');
+------------------------+-----------------------+
| soundex('John Carter') | soundex('JhonCarter') |
+------------------------+-----------------------+
| J52636                 | J52636                |
+------------------------+-----------------------+
```

See also:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_soundex
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex